# highlight div acorrding to respective clicked element

Tags: jquery

i have five divs

```
<div  id="box1">content 1</div>
<div  id="box2">content 2</div>
<div  id="box3">content 3</div>
<div  id="box4">content 4</div>
<div  id="box5">content 5</div>
```

each that is highlight accordingly when i click on a certain link

```
<a class="light" id="1">link 1</a>
<a class="light" id="2">link 2</a>
<a class="light" id="3">link 3</a>
<a class="light" id="4">link 4</a>
<a class="light" id="5">link 5</a>
```

this is my jquery

```
$(".light").live("click", function(){
var id = $(this).attr('id');
$("box"+id).css({'background':'red'});

});
```

stuck at this point, i would like to dehighlight the previous box when i click on another link, and vice versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have missed the `#` sign and please note that if the doctype of the page is not HTML5, `id` names must begin with a letter A-Z or a-z.

```
$(".light").live("click", function(){ // you can also use `on()` instead of `live()` which is deprecated
    var id = this.id;
    $('div[id^="box"]').css({'background':'none'})
    $("#box"+id).css({'background':'red'});
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2Frrr/1/)

Comment: Numeric IDs are valid as per HTML5 spec. +1 now `=]`

Comment: just to back your solution `:)` - http://jsfiddle.net/XdxRj/  see a toggling version below: you could do the same if you want. rest feel free to use the demo!

Answer (score 1):

Hey see here: http://jsfiddle.net/gehZ8/ **A Toggling version here** http://jsfiddle.net/gehZ8/1/

Plz note you have id as `number`, you could do this `var id = $(this).attr('id').replace(/a/, '');` will fetch you the last number from the string and then adds it to your div logic, rest feel free to play around `:)`

Also instead of `live` if you are using latest Jquery use `.on` event.

Hope this helps, `B-)`

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".light").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id').replace(/a/, '');

        $("#box" + id).css({
            'background': 'red'
        });


    });
});
```

Comment: Hiya @user836910 and you downvoted me for that ? brilliant `:)` what do you mean `highlighted` last div? testing in chrome seems to be behaving fine?

Answer (score 0):

If you're highlighting and using the same color everytime, it's easier to apply/remove classes on click.

**The CSS**

```
.highlight{
  background-color: red;
}
```

**The jQuery**

```
$('.light').live('click', function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  $('[id^=box]').removeClass('highlight');
  $('#box'+id).addClass('highlight');
});
```

Comment: Indeed a viable solution +1 for you as well see demo http://jsfiddle.net/BWbHw/ **also** you can make it toggling like I did anyhoo feel free to use the demo `:)`

Answer (score 0):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ijorux/2/edit)*

You don't need all that `ID`s all around. just classes:

```
<a href="#" class="light">link 1</a>
<div class="box">content 1</div>
```

And get the `index` of the clicked link:

```
$("a.light").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var thisIndex = $(this).index();
  $('.box').eq(thisIndex).css({background:'red'}).siblings().css({background:'none'});
});
```

I used `.eq()` to first point to the same indexed `.box` and targeted all other boxes (to undo the background) using `.siblings()`;

[Find out more amazing stuff reading the DOCS](http://api.jquery.com/)

If you want to validate your HTML use `href=""` attribute for your links and than, to prevent the default click behavior use the jQuery `e.preventDefault()`.

**I used the `.on()` method as from jQuery 1.7+ `.live()` is deprecated.**